# Finding R equivalent

Tags: resistance

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0Q8kI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When finding Req between M and N i can't understand why current isn't flowing in R3 and R4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I redrew your schematic. Do you see it now? By symmetry you can see that the voltage across R3 and R4 will be zero. So, using Ohms law, 0/R = 0.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fem6e3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I can see the symetry but what are the "consequences" of that?

Comment: @Loukil-M I think mkeith *could* do a better job of drawing the schematic to get the point across. But, actually, it's hard to say what will communicate better in your mind. So before I screw around with a slight modification, let me use some words. Imagine that \$R_3\$ and \$R_4\$ were removed, above. Just rip them out. No wire left. Just open holes. Wouldn't the node voltages at each of the three dividers be the same no matter what voltage was applied between M and N? Now imagine putting one of those resistors back in place. If the node voltages were the same before, would any current flow?

Comment: The consequences of the symmetry are that the nodes on either side of R3 and R4 have the same voltage. This means that the current through R3 and R4 will be zero. Any time the voltage across a resistor is zero, the current through the resistor is also zero (by Ohm's law).

Comment: its because all are 1k resistors.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine applying a voltage from M to N.

The circuit is symmetrical so there would be no reason for current to flow "sideways" through R3, R4. Hence you can ignore them. The equivalent resistance would be the same if they were shorts or completely open.

Answer (score 0):

All the answers are pretty good but just to give a pictorial view of what jonk meant, here's an easy to digest transformation for beginners. 
[image]